# Custom label for vb chart

Tags: vb.net, mschart

#Custom label for vb chart#

I have a datatable like this

| XValue | YValue | Title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A |
| 2 | 2 | B |
| 3 | 3 | C |

I want to display a vb chart like this

```
6|
5|
4|
3|      *C
2|    *B
1|  *A
0|______________________
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 5 8 9
```

so far i can only display this

```
6|
5|
4|
3|      *3
2|    *2
1|  *1
0|______________________
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 5 8 9
```

this is my code below

```
        Chart20.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Minimum = 60
        Chart20.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Maximum = 220

        Chart20.Series("TEMP").Points.Clear()

        Try
            CONN.Open()
            COMMAND = CONN.CreateCommand

            QUERY = "SELECT XValue,YValue,Title FROM vitals"
            COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(QUERY, CONN)
            READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader

            While READER.Read
                    Chart20.Series("TEMP").Points.AddXY(READER.GetString("YValue"), READER.GetString("XValue"))
            End While

            CONN.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            CONN.Close()
            MsgBox(ex.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End Try
```

Can you help me out pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Sub ShowPointLabels()

        Chart20.Series("TEMP").Points.Clear()

        Try
            CONN.Open()
            COMMAND = CONN.CreateCommand

            QUERY = "SELECT * FROM vitals"
            COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(QUERY, CONN)
            READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader

            For Each d In READER
                Chart20.Series("TEMP").Points(Chart20.Series("TEMP").Points.AddXY(READER.GetString("XValue"), READER.GetString("YValue"))).Label = READER.GetString("Title")
            Next

            CONN.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            CONN.Close()
            MsgBox(ex.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

I modified @Andrew Morton Answer to a simplified result and it works perfectly for me. I hope this helps somebody as well

Answer (score 4):

If you set the .Label, .Font, .LabelBackColor, and .LabelForeColor properties you can see the labels of the points, e.g. I put a Chart control on a Form with this code:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting

Public Class Form1

    Class Datum
        Property X As Integer
        Property Y As Integer
        Property Title As String

        Sub New(x As Integer, y As Integer, t As String)
            Me.X = x
            Me.Y = y
            Me.Title = t
        End Sub

    End Class

    Sub ShowPointLabels()
        Dim data = New List(Of Datum) From {New Datum(1, 1, "A"),
                                            New Datum(2, 2, "B"),
                                            New Datum(3, 3, "C")}

        Chart1.Series.Clear()
        Dim ds As New Series("Sample")
        ds.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point

        Dim fnt = New Font("Arial", 12)

        For Each d In data
            Dim n = ds.Points.AddXY(d.X, d.Y)
            Dim p = ds.Points(n)
            p.Font = fnt
            p.Label = d.Title
            p.LabelBackColor = Color.PaleGoldenrod
            p.LabelForeColor = Color.DarkBlue
            p.LabelToolTip = "This is the label for " & d.Title

        Next

        Chart1.Series.Add(ds)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ShowPointLabels()

    End Sub

End Class
```

To get this:

[image: Chart with data labels]

Also, it would be better to read all the data from the database in one step, in the next step add the data to the chart series, and finally add the series to the chart. That keeps the time that the connection to the database is open to a minimum and avoids the time taken to update the chart every time a point is added.

Comment: can i use the same method with mysql??

Comment: @Icefall007 I didn't want to set up a database table to make up some sample data, so I just made it up in the example code. You can use whatever method you like to retrieve the data. The important part is the very first sentence of my answer.

Comment: I modified @AndrewMorton Answer to a simplified result and it works perfectly for me. I hope this helps somebody as well